# Срез структур, вложенный в структуру

Tags: golang, golang-struct

Приведите пример, пожалуйста. Не могу разобраться. В идеале, хотелось бы видеть пример добавления уже готового массива структур в поле главной структуры, которое отвечает за срез вложенных структур.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что именно у вас вызывает трудности?

```golang
type A struct {
    Bs []B
}

type B struct {
    N int
}

// …

var a = A{}
var bs = []B{{1}, {2}}
a.Bs = bs
fmt.Printf("%+v", a)
// Output:
//   {Bs:[{N:1} {N:2}]}
```